# Finding Hybridization of Certain Atoms in Lewis Structure

Tags: hybridization, lewis-structure

[image]

So, I'm having trouble with this problem. We're given this incomplete lewis structure and asked to find the hybridization of 3 of the atoms.

I figured that the labelled Cl would be sp3 because of it's 1 single bond and the 3 lone pairs that would be on it.
I also thought the labelled C would be sp2 because of the 2 single bonds and 1 lone pair.
Now, I was confused at to what the labelled O would be. I thought maybe it would have 3 lone pairs but that doesn't seem to be correct, since my sp3 answer was rejected.

Any insight on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: A lone pair on C would be quite an unusual thing to find. Consider double bonds instead. Yes, some of these bonds are double, and they won't tell you which. But you may guess...

Comment: You should never consider halogens hybridised in any way.

Comment: Still, if confronted with a question like this one, go with $sp^3$ for Cl, because that's what they want from you.

Comment: Well, if you see valency of Oxygen is 2, but its making only 1 bond. Thats  enough for hint, and as @IvanNeretin said "some of these bonds are double, and they won't tell you which. But you may guess..."